# How to print logs in Cucumber JS report file?

Tags: cucumber, cucumberjs

I am using Cucumber JS and I want to print logs (console logs or any type of log) on the report as well. Is there any way to achieve this?

Comment: Hello, what are you using to generate the report ? Anyway, you can do it using ```this.attach``` method https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber-js/blob/main/docs/support_files/attachments.md